# How to read excel 2007 in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My server does't have any Microsoft Office and I dont want to install Microsoft office.

When I use this code for reading an Excel 2007 file

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myOldExcelFile.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";
```

It cannot read the Excel file. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Copy the Interop.Excel DLL from any system add the Reference to the Project, So taht you can able to read the excel. no need of OLEDB.

Comment: @AkshayJoy referencing the Interop.Excel without Excel installed ins't going to do much... and remember this is server side so please see [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: You can copy the Inteop DLL from any system. add the Reference to the Project. you can easily operate the Excel witht the Interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to see your not installing Office on the server and following [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Make sure you have the [Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed on the server, this is for Office 2010 (v14), the 2007 (v12) should be easy to find.

Here it is: [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

> EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

MS Office doesn't have to be installed.

Example script to open a `.xlsx`:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
```

```
// Get the file we are going to process
var existingFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
// Open and read the XlSX file.
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    // Get the work book in the file
    ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
    if (workBook != null)
    {
        if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
        {
            // Get the first worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();

            // read some data
            object col1Header = currentWorksheet.Cells[0, 1].Value;
            ...
```

code sample from: http://blog.fryhard.com/archive/2010/10/28/reading-xlsx-files-using-c-and-epplus.aspx

Comment: Must feel so good about to reach that 10K mark, showing some sportsmanship:)

Comment: @JeremyThompson :) gracias

Comment: I know it is 7 years later, but just came to say the OP requested *.xls - not *.xlsx. I'm dealing with the same problem. A 3rd party program is producing an *.xls file (not *.xlsx) and I need to read that file rather than having to convert it to xlsx first.

Answer (score 0):

//Start up excel to read the excel file in question

the Sample code will help you to achieve this.

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = null;

    ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    if (ExcelObj == null)

    {

     MessageBox.Show("ERROR: EXCEL couldn't be started!");

     System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();

    }


    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,

    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,

    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,

    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);


    for(int x = 1; x <= 29; x++)

    {

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A"+x.ToString(), "I" + x.ToString());

    System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.get_Value(range.);

    string[] strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);

    }
```

Comment: Did you see my comment above? about KB 257757? The Interop's wont work without Office installed and to reiterate this is Server-Side.

Comment: You can copy the DLL from any system..  Crate and Interop achieve this. use tlbimp to create an Interop.

Comment: So to clarify, you are saying its possible to use the Interop.Excel without Excel installed?

Comment: Ya.. you can create an Interop using Excel DLL, use tlbimp , read the msdn page for tlbimp, then you can add the reference to the Project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I know very well about the PIA's and tmbimp. What I'm saying is that **you cannot use Interop.Excel.DLL without Excel installed**. Then I reference a KB article 257757 (which I know off by heart) that states its a `bad` idea to install office on a server and do automation tasks. Hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: hey,,,  you can create the Interop in any system (system having Excel Interop other than server). then you can able to refer.or you can have DLLIMPORT

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `.dll` from microsoft site and use it in your project.
You don't need to install microsoft excel there.

You can read it using ado.net

```
    var myConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
       Data Source='c:\\Language_Batch1_OneClick.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
    var myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    var upCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    int i = 0;
    try
    {

        string sql = null;
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        sql = "select ANSWER_CODE,Punjabi from [Batch_Lang_1$]";
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        var dataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var langText = dataReader["Punjabi"].ToString();
        }
```